# javascript method chaining comparison

Tags: javascript

I was trying to chain ex1 and ex2 functions and display true or false after comparing value provided in the chained methods.

```
function test() {
   var ex1 = function(parm) {
      return this;
   }

   var ex2 = function(par) {
      return this;
   }

   var result = function() {
      console.log('compare and display a boolean result '+ex1(parm).ex2(par));
   }
};
var res = test();
res.ex1('Sam').ex2('Eddie').result();
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: How do I do the comparison and display the result?

Comment: do you have only two values to compare?

Comment: Yes. I only have two values to compare. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Didn't my solution help? Are you looking for more details before you could accept the solution?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```js
function Test() {
  this.ex1 = function(parm) {
    this.param1 = parm;
    return this;
  }

  this.ex2 = function(par) {
    this.param2 = par;
    return this;
  }

  this.result = function() {

    console.log('compare and display a boolean result ' + (this.param1 == this.param2));
  }
  //return this;
};
var res = new Test();
res.ex1('Sam').ex2('Sam').result();
```

Edited my answer so as not to pollute the global namespace as suggested by **Ced**. Also, if you go this route, move your methods from within constructor function to prototype object of `Test`. So, as an example ex1 should be written like

```
Test.prototype.ex1 = function(parm) {
               this.parm = parm;
               return this;
           }
```

Same goes for other methods.

Comment: I'd suggest not doing this as it's bad practice. when calling your function this points to the window.

Comment: I am going to edit my answer to incorporate your point for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to remove my downvote, but it says I cannot do it after 5 minutes. Sorry

Comment: @Ced Incorporated your comment. Also, you can rename test to Test! in your solution.

Comment: @Ced Thanks Ced! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could return an object with a function inside and if the inner function is called, the return theresult without using another function for calling.

```js
function test(value1) {
    return {
        equals: function (value2) {
            return value1 === value2;
        }
    };
}

console.log(test(1).equals(1));
console.log(test(1).equals(2));
```

For using the above with an explict calling of `result`, you could add a result property in the return object, like

```js
function test(value1) {
    return {
        equals: function (value2) {
            return {
                result: function () {
                    return value1 === value2;
                }
            };
        }
    };
}

console.log(test(1).equals(1).result());
console.log(test(1).equals(2).result());
```

The nearly the same as above with an object with all properties

```js
function test(value1) {
    var v2,
        object = {
        equals: function (value2) {
            v2 = value2;
            return object;
        },
        result: function () {
            return value1 === v2;
        }
    };
    return object;
}

console.log(test(1).equals(1).result());
console.log(test(1).equals(2).result());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a object literal, and make this more readable:

```js
var Test = {
   that: function(param) {
      this.param1 = param;
      return this;
   },
   isEqualTo: function(param) {
      this.param2 = param;
      return this.param1 === this.param2;
   }
};

console.log(Test.that('abc').isEqualTo('cba')); // false
console.log(Test.that('123').isEqualTo('321')); // false
console.log(Test.that('asd').isEqualTo('asd')); // true
console.log(Test.that('tre').isEqualTo('tre')); // true

// or just reusing

Test.that('word');
console.log(Test.isEqualTo('drow')); // false
console.log(Test.isEqualTo('world')); // false
console.log(Test.isEqualTo('word')); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function test() {
   var ex1 = function(parm) {
      return this;
   }

   var ex2 = function(par) {
      return this;
   }

   var result = function() {
      console.log('compare and display a boolean result '+ex1(parm).ex2(par));
   }
};
```

So when this executes it returns nothing:

```
var res = Test();
```

Thus res is undefined. Thus ex1 doesn't exists on undefined by definition.

```
res.ex1('Sam').ex2('Eddie').result();
```

What the answer above me suggest is to return this. **Don't** do that.

```
function test() {
  this.ex1 = function(parm) {
    this.param1 = parm;
    return this;
  }

  this.ex2 = function(par) {
    this.param2 = par;
    return this;
  }

  this.result = function() {

    console.log('compare and display a boolean result ' + (this.param1 == this.param2));
  }
  return this;
};
```

When it enters the function `this` equals windows. Thus you are polluting the window object.

What you could do instead:

```
function Test() {
   this.parm;
   this.par;
   this.ex1 = function(parm) {
      this.parm = parm;
      return this;
   }

   this.ex2 = function(par) {
      this.par = par;

      return this;
   }

   this.result = function() {
      console.log('compare and display a boolean result '+ (this.parm === this.par));
   }
};
var res = new Test();

res.ex1('Sam').ex2('Eddie').result();
```

You call new Test() : a new object is created `{}` where the this value points to it. Then the function is executed. So the object now contains the functions and doesn't pollute your window.

Comment: Good point about not polluting the global namespace. But OP didn't get that far so the solution was to solve his immediate problem. By the way, if you go `constructor` function route, then I would suggest rename `test` to `Test` as well since it is the convention.

Comment: @PankajShukla I actually think he doesn't have an use case... If you are doing this type of function I bet it's for learning purpose. else he would use `===`. If it's for learning purpose I think it's better to explain him a bit what's going on.

Comment: Additionally, if OP goes constructor function route he also needs to move the methods from within constructor to prototype object of Test. Attaching methods inside constructor function is not the right practice.